# Oracle SQL for Last Business Day of Current Month including federal holidays in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to find the Oracle SQL for finding the last business day of current month and also last business day of previous month. Both cases should consider the federal holidays calendar.

For Example:

- Last Business Day of Current Month
- If am running as of date 15th November, 2019

I should technically get my output as 29th November since 28th is Thanksgiving holiday.

Answer (score 4):

Store those federal holidays in a holidays table as `DATE` type and then 
try something like this: Find the oldest ( `MAX` ) day in the last seven days of the month that is neither a Saturday or a Sunday nor a holiday mentioned in 
the holidays table.

The assumptions here are that 1) not all seven days at the end of the month can all be holidays or weekend and 2) Saturday and Sundays are off. You may adjust the `level` or where clause accordingly, depending on whether the above assumption should always hold true or not.

```
SELECT MAX(dt) AS last_working_day 
FROM
(
SELECT last_day(SYSDATE) - level + 1 as dt
FROM dual CONNECT BY
     level <= 7  -- the last seven days of the month
     )  WHERE TO_CHAR(dt,'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = AMERICAN') NOT IN ('SAT','SUN')
     AND dt NOT IN ( SELECT holiday from federal_holidays );
```

A much better approach would be to have a Calendar table with all the dates of the year and predefined column called `isbusinessday`. Then the query would be much simpler.

```
SELECT MAX(dt)
  FROM calendar
  WHERE isbusinessday = 'Y' 
AND TO_CHAR(dt,'YYYYMM') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMM');
```

Answer (score 1):

Having a holiday table is working in general, however it requires some maintenance as certain holidays are moving. For example Thanksgiving Day is the 4th Thursday in November, i.e. it varies from November 22 to November 28.

You can also use the Oracle build-in Scheduler. Usually it is used to control the `SCHEDULER JOBS` but I don't see any reason why it should not be used for something else.

First create a list of federal holidays, for example this:

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE(schedule_name => 'CHRISTMAS', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDATE=1225', comments => 'December 25');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE(schedule_name => 'COLUMBUS_DAY', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTH=OCT;BYDAY=2 MON', comments => '2nd Monday in October');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE(schedule_name => 'INDEPENDENCE_DAY', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDATE=0704', comments => 'July 4');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE(schedule_name => 'MARTIN_LUTHER_KING_DAY', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTH=JAN;BYDAY=3 MON', comments => '3rd Monday in January');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE(schedule_name => 'MEMORIAL_DAY', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTH=MAY;BYDAY=-1 MON', comments => 'Last Monday of May');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE(schedule_name => 'NEW_YEARS_DAY', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDATE=0101', comments => 'January 1');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE(schedule_name => 'THANKSGIVING', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTH=NOV;BYDAY=4 THU', comments => '4th Thursday in November');
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE(schedule_name => 'WASHINGTONS_BIRTHDAY', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTH=FEB;BYDAY=3 MON', comments => '3rd Monday in February');

    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE(schedule_name => 'WEEKEND', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=SAT,SUN');

    -- Combined schedule for all federal holidays 
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULE(schedule_name => 'FEDERAL_HOLIDAYS', repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;INTERSECT=CHRISTMAS,INDEPENDENCE_DAY,MARTIN_LUTHER_KING_DAY,MEMORIAL_DAY,NEW_YEARS_DAY,THANKSGIVING,WASHINGTONS_BIRTHDAY');

END;
/
```

Have a look at [Calendaring Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#BABFBCEF) to see how `repeat_interval` needs to be specified.

Then you can use procedure `DBMS_SCHEDULER.EVALUATE_CALENDAR_STRING` to get your date:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LAST_BUSINESS_DAY(today IN TIMESTAMP DEFAULT SYSTIMESTAMP) RETURN TIMESTAMP AS 
    return_date_after TIMESTAMP := TRUNC(today);
    next_run_date TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN

    LOOP
        DBMS_SCHEDULER.EVALUATE_CALENDAR_STRING('FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;EXCLUDE=FEDERAL_HOLIDAYS,WEEKEND', NULL, return_date_after, next_run_date);
        EXIT WHEN next_run_date >= LAST_DAY(TRUNC(today));
        return_date_after := next_run_date;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN return_date_after;   
END LAST_BUSINESS_DAY;
```