# Oracle query to get the number of business days between 2 dates, excluding holidays

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g

We are using Oracle 11.

In our CASE WHEN statement, I need to check if the number of days between the 2 dates are > 3 business days (so excluding weekends and holidays).

```
    CASE WHEN end_date - start_date > 3  THEN 0  --> this includes weekend 
        and holidays
WHEN CODE = 1 THEN 1
WHEN CODE =2 THEN 2
ELSE 3
END AS MyColumn
```

Say I have a holiday calendar table that has column HolidayDates that contains all the holidays, for ex: 12/25/2018, 12/31/2018, etc.

```
HolidayDates
12/25/2018
12/31/2018
```

So, if

Date1 = 1/2/19 (Wednesday)

Date2 = 12/27/18 (Thursday)

The number of business days in between Date1 and Date2 is 3 days (12/27, 12/28 and 12/31).

The below query will get the number of business days excluding weekends.

How do I also exclude holidays in this query ?

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD "("DY")"') AS start_date,

   ( TRUNC( end_date, 'IW' ) - TRUNC( start_date, 'IW' ) ) * 5 / 7
   + LEAST( TRUNC( end_date   ) - TRUNC( end_date,   'IW' ) + 1, 5 )
   - LEAST( TRUNC( start_date ) - TRUNC( start_date, 'IW' ), 5 )
     AS Num_Week_Days
FROM   table_name;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Oracle has nothing built-in to handle public holidays. You'll need to create a table of your own to hold them. [Have a pipe at this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52953784/146325). If that doesn't help there are plenty of others to check. [Find them here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=oracle+calendar+holiday).

Comment: `- (select COUNT(*) from HolidayDates where HolDate between start_date+1 and end_date)`?

Comment: Hi, I have my own Holiday calendar table that has column HolidayDates as mentioned above.

Comment: This is a follow on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54370122/1509264) and is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43632677/function-to-get-number-of-weekdays-between-two-dates-excluding-holidays/43633234#43633234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the code in [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43632677/function-to-get-number-of-weekdays-between-two-dates-excluding-holidays/43633234#43633234) and converting it from a function to a query gives:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Holidays ( HolidayDates ) AS
SELECT DATE '2018-12-25' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2018-12-31' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table_name ( start_date, end_date ) AS
SELECT DATE '2018-12-21', DATE '2018-12-26' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2018-12-28', DATE '2019-01-01' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT t.*,
       ( TRUNC( end_date, 'IW' ) - TRUNC( start_date, 'IW' ) ) * 5 / 7
       + LEAST( TRUNC( end_date   ) - TRUNC( end_date,   'IW' ) + 1, 5 )
       - LEAST( TRUNC( start_date ) - TRUNC( start_date, 'IW' ), 5 )
       - ( SELECT COUNT(1)
           FROM   holidays
           WHERE  HolidayDates BETWEEN t.start_date AND t.end_date
           -- Exclude any weekend holidays so we don't double count.
           AND    TRUNC( HolidayDates ) - TRUNC( HolidayDates, 'IW' ) <= 5
         )
       AS Num_Week_Days
FROM   table_name t;
```

**Output**:

```
START_DATE | END_DATE  | NUM_WEEK_DAYS
:--------- | :-------- | ------------:
21-DEC-18  | 26-DEC-18 |             3
28-DEC-18  | 01-JAN-19 |             2
01-JAN-19  | 07-JAN-19 |             5
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9525da7456aac3d0956a998af1a0a5f7)*